# How to delete or join paralleled lines in ArcGIS, QGIS or R?

Tags: python, r, gis, arcgis, qgis

I have a large shapefile data for railroads. The railroads have two paralleled lines (representing two tracks). I want to keep one line and delete the other line. I think we can delete one paralleled line or join them to one line. But I don't know how to do this. Does anyone know how to do this? Any related software (ArcGIS, QGIS or R) is welcome. Many thanks!